# How to determine if a state is a fixed point in a Hopfield network?

Tags: neural-networks

I have been reading a lot and I am still unsure of how to determine this. Let's say I have an initial binary state vector (1, 1, 1). How would I go about determining whether (1, 1, 1) is a fixed point in the network?

My initial understanding was to put the state through the network and if it converged to (1, 1, 1) then it is a fixed point. However I have a feeling it is not as simple as that.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your intuition is right. A state is a fixed point in a Hopfield network if it is a local minima of the energy function. In other words, some binary state vector $x$ is a fixed point if and only if every other state vector at hamming distance $1$ from $x$ has higher energy. The simplest way to determine if a state is a fixed point is to iterate over each dimension of the state and try to update it. If the state doesn't change then it is a fixed point.

Edit: Too long for comment.

I think you might be confusing *global* and *local* minima. If you take some state (binary vector) $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, and iterate the dynamics of the network until nothing changes$^{1}$, you will have converged on a fixed point, call it $\mathbf{x}^\prime$. This $\mathbf{x}^\prime$ is a local minima of the energy function. By definition this means that every state at hamming distance 1 (those that differ by 1 bit) will have higher energy. If this was not the case then there exists some $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that flipping position $i$ in $\mathbf{x}^\prime$ would give a state with lower energy. But this means when choosing to update bit $i$, you would have flipped it$^2$.

Now, what this doesn't mean is the that this is the *global* minima of the energy function. There could be a state that differs by 2 bits from $\mathbf{x}^\prime$ with lower energy. But you can never reach it from $\mathbf{x}^\prime$ by updating a single bit/unit at a time. So you are trapped at $\mathbf{x}^\prime$, in a local minima of the energy function.

[1] This is important, you need to make a full pass over all the postions in the state vector without anything changing to ensure you have converged to a fixed point.

[2] The relation between the energy function and the dynamics of asynchronously updating units is what makes Hopfield networks interesting. The idea that we can say something global about the network (the energy function) based on local interactions is neat.

Comment: There are many papers with Hopfield network variations that have input and output.  A Hopfield vector state equation is the definition of its fixed point.  You don't need to iterate anything to determine whether a state is fixed point.

Comment: @Gene there are lots of variations of lots of things, but I think it is safe to assume that OP is interested in the original formulation. I'm also unsure of what you mean by "Hopfield vector state equation." The energy function?

Comment: So is it possible for there to be a fixed point that is not a local minima?

Comment: No, every fixed point is a local minima of the energy function. Furthermore, when you iterate the dynamics of the network (randomly pick a unit, update it) you are guaranteed to converge to one of these local minima.

Comment: Yes that would definitely make sense. A part of my assignment tells me to compare the fixed points energy with the energies of its neighbours.  Eg fixed points (1, 1, 1), neighbours are states that only differ by one bit, e.g. (0, 1, 1) etc. Now I interpret this as that a fixed point may not have the minimal energy, which doesn't make sense. Again back to my initial understanding, the energy should drop to a minimum as iterations increase. I don't get how it relates to its neighbours?

Comment: @KevinLee My comment got too long, see the update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot you've been a great help. Shame my results don't quite reflect what is meant to happen. I guess down to dodgy implementation. At least I will know it for the exam.

Comment: @KevinLee glad it helped. I wrote a quick demo in julia, you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/thomlake/11287768)

Answer (score -1):

It's as simple as that.  Write out the state equation.  Substitute the state vector.  Verify that equality holds.   If it does, then you have a fixed point.

Note that what you're calling a state vector probably isn't one in the typical definition of that term.  The vector of neuron *inputs* is usually called the state vector. It would be unusual (though of course not impossible) for this to be all 1's.

If what you actually have is the *output* vector, then you can solve for the state vector using the feedback function.  Then verify the resulting state vector is consistent with the outputs.  If so, then you have a fixed point.

Comment: [Hopfield networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network) don't really have a notion of input and output. You can think of them as a deterministic analog of a fully visible Boltzmann machine/markov random field with pairwise and unary potentials.